# Django forms Customising model form field labels

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to customise the label for a django model form:

```
class SupplyTypeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EUser
        fields = ('service_type', 'online_account')
        labels = {
            'online_account': _('Do you have an online account with any of your suppliers'),
        }
```

But I get the error: `NameError: name '_' is not defined`

However the django docs mention to do it this way, so I'm not clear what's wrong (the underscore is strange and I'm not sure why it is being used here). If I remove it works and the error disappears

Any reason why the docs have it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: Have you made the correct import? `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`

Comment: @lambo477 you should write this an answer!

Comment: @DerekKwok thanks, I've completed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the correct import:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

Comment: It is not required to use '_', you can completely remove it if you don't want multilingual support in your Django application. If you want then import is required as it allows us to place translation texts in .py files so that the 'django-admin makemessages' could easily identify the locations of translation texts.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _` to use `_()`

Comment: should I fill this one in too?